# RabbitMQ One consumer receives all messages at a time

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have one consumer who consumes 8 messages at a time from a single queue. The problem is that the consumer always waits for all 8 messages to be sent and does not take new ones for processing. Is it possible to set up so that the consumer in the queue works completely asynchronously and immediately consumes messages as soon as he sends it, rather than waiting for all 8 to be sent?

```
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Proxy> context)
    {
       _service.SendMessage(sms); // does certain actions for sending messages
       return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Specific actions are:
-write to the database
-sending to a specific server that sends a response

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: Yes, code would be helpful. Because the way it works with all transports is each message added to the queue, via send or publish, is consumed immediately.

Comment: @Chris Patterson, add some code, maybe to be a helpful.